# Move a hidden web part between zones using the user interface

Tags: web-part, front-end, hidden

I have a Publishing page with a number of web parts - upon changing the page layout recently, some of the web parts disappeared (because the web part zones changed).

**Is it possible to move these web parts from their old (missing) zones to a zone that is on the page**, using only the user interface?

All of the web parts are still listed in the `Modify Web Parts` menu in the page toolbar, but the `Zone` field on the web part settings menu is disabled for all of these parts (and just says `Title Bar`).  The parts are also listed on `?contents=1` as well, but that screen does not seem to have any mechanism for moving the web parts to a different zone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit the page. Go to Insert tab on the ribbon and select Web Part. In the Categories list on the left-hand side scroll down to Closed Web Parts and select it. You should then be able to select the closed web parts and add them to one of the existing zones.

Comment: Thanks @SPDoctor. I did have to close the web parts first via `?contents=1` before they were available in the list of Closed Web Parts (because they weren't actually closed - just not in a valid web part zone), but once I did this I was able to move them back on to the page.